# How to deploy angular universal in IIS?

Tags: angular-universal

I am facing problem with deploying angular universal application in IIS. In angular universal two dist folder is created one is dist for client and another is dist-server, when I try to host , I am giving path of dist folder ,site is running but pages not rendered from server.

Comment: Same problem !! did you find any solution to it?

Comment: same problem for me

Comment: any update frnds

Comment: What folder are you uploading to the server? and can you share some code please?

Comment: I didn't find any solution to host it on IIS. If you find any solution please inform us, your help is valuable for us.

Comment: same problem for me

Comment: To use server-side rendering, you need a backend stack. For IIS this most likely means ASP.NET Core. As Budda points out, `SpaServices` have been removed in .NET 5, but .NET Core 3.1 will still be supported until december 2022. I've written an article on [how to use ASP.NET Core and angular together with SSR](https://pieterjandeclippel.medium.com/server-side-rendering-in-asp-net-core-angular-update-705c0ec01931), but the way-to changes all the time and I'm not sure if the article would still be working with the latest version of angular + .NET Core 3.1.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, not that I found the solution, but I guess I found why there is no solution, at least for now.

Here are a few things to learn that will help realize why you should not try host Angular SSR under IIS.

1. The first thing to realize is that when you build a 'regular' Angular application you get typical set of file that you can host at pretty much any server. TBH, I'm not familiar with many servers, but you can certainly host those with IIS. But when you build Angular in SSR mode, you get files that are supposed to be hosted with Node.js
2. To host Angular in SSR mode, you could create ASP.NET Angular application, and turn it into SSR mode. Unfortunately, seems like this stopped working in .NET 5 (at least this is what many other people complain about as well: I'd provide a few links but I don't have those handy)

I think the option is to wait for MS to implement support for SSR Angular in .NET 5. In the meantime, probably a good idea is to host it under Node.js.

P.S. I'm not a guru on this topic, just shared what I've learned so far. If someone can fill in gaps or correct me, I'd appreciated it. Thanks!